Probability that randomly chosen balls have a nonempty common intersection
Fix some $0 < r < 1$. A collection of points $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are chosen independently and uniformly at random from the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^d$.
What is the probability that the intersection $\cap_{i = 1}^n B_r (x_i)$ is nonempty?
Note: Here $B_r (x_i)$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ around $x_i$.
Comments: The question as posed is rather open ended since there may not be a simple expression for the probability. If an exact solution is hard or impossible to find, I would still be interested in asymptotic/approximate results.
Even the case $d = 1$ seems to be interesting, and may admit a reasonably simple exact expression.

In the regime $0<r\le R<1$ with fixed $R$, one can get $\mathbb P(d,n,r)=r^{d(n-1)}n^d e^{O(d)}$ where the implicit constant in $O()$ depends on $R$ only. Is this good enough for your purposes, or do you want higher precision? Also I have no doubt that this problem has been considered somewhere, so literature search may be your friend here.

@fedja I actually don’t have any particular application in mind for this result - it seemed interesting in itself, and like you say it seems pretty canonical. I find that if one considers “canonical” situations they almost always lead to some pretty interesting analysis and links to other stuff. Of course I do not have a definition of canonical :P

Indeed, it is a nice question by itself. I'll wait a bit in the hope that someone more knowledgeable than I will post a proof of or a reference to a more accurate asymptotic result than the one I mentioned, but if it doesn't happen soon, I'll probably post my simple bounds at some point :-)

@fedja Sounds good, I appreciate you trying out my problem :D

The case $d=1$ is simple. Then the probability in question is
$$p:=P(V-U\le r),$$
where $U$ and $V$ are, respectively, the smallest and largest order statistics for an iid random sample of size $n$ from the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ (rescaling from the 1-dimensional unit ball $[-1,1]$). The joint pdf of $(U,V)$ is given by
$$f(u,v)=n(n-1)(v-u)^{n-2}\,1(0<u<v<1)$$
(assuming $n\ge2$). So,
$$p=\int_0^1\int_0^1 du\,dv\,f(u,v)\,1(v-u\le r) 
=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }r>1,\\
r^{n-1}(n+r-nr)&\text{ if }r\in[0,1]. 
\end{cases}  $$

In the last quantity, should it be max or min?

@KhashF : It is neither. :-) This is now fixed. Thank you for your comment.

For fixed $r < 1/2$ we can find upper and lower bounds which at least tell us that $$-\log \mathbb{P}\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^n B_r(x_i) \not= \emptyset\right] \asymp d(n-1)$$
for $n \geq 2$.
Finding the lower-order terms remains an interesting problem (my crude bound above doesn't give us Iosif's $n+r-nr$ term, for example).
If there is a point of common intersection, then $x_2, \dots, x_n \in B_{2r}(x_1)$. The volume of $B_{2r}(x_1) \cap B_1(0)$ is bounded above by $\theta_d (2r)^{d}$ (where $\theta_d$ is the volume of $B_1(0)$), so $\mathbb{P}[x_2, \dots, x_n \in B_{2r}(x_1)] \leq (2r)^{d(n-1)}$ is our upper bound.
For the lower bound, if $x_2, \dots, x_n \in B_r(x_1)$, then the intersection of all $n$ balls contains $x_1$. The volume of $B_r(x_1) \cap B_1(0)$ is minimised when $x_1$ is at the boundary, and since $r < 1/2$ this volume is bounded below by $c_{1/4}r^d$, where $c_{1/4}$ is the volume of the spherical cap $\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^d : \|z\|\leq 1, z_1 \geq 1/4 \}$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}[\cap_{i=1}^n B_r(x_i) \not= \emptyset] \geq (\frac{c_{1/4}}{\theta_d} r^d)^{n-1}$.
Unfortunately the upper bound is trivial when $r \in (1/2,1)$, but the question is probably the most interesting when $r$ is close to 1. A related question might be: if we place $n$ points, what can we say about the minimum radius $R_n$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} B_{R_n}(x_i) \not= \emptyset$? Obviously $R_n \uparrow 1$, but the size of $1-R_n$ should be interesting.
Edit:
I came across a paper today which is very closely related to the problem when $r=1$ (so the intersection is almost-surely non-empty, but the volume and shape are still interesting questions, and closely related to the probability that the intersection is non-empty when $r < 1$): https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-applied-probability/article/intersections-of-random-sets/F94BF856EBE488909E2132C3BEBD0DDC Their Proposition 1.1 gives asymptotics for the expected volume of the intersection, and their Theorem 1.2 says that (suitably rescaled) the limiting shape of the intersection is the same as the cell containing the origin in a Poisson hyperplane model.

You can do a bit better: in the regime $r<1/3$, say, you have $\mathbb P(d,n,r)=r^{d(n-1)}n^d e^{O(d)}$ (I don't know if $O(d)$ is positive or negative though). If $r$ is close to $1$, the boundary effect becomes significant and I cannot tell much yet.
